# Jstree - need to combine two pieces of java script what is the correct syntax?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I know very limited javascript. Here is the beginning piece:

```
$("#jstree").jstree()
```

Now I need to add two pieces of code, here is the first:

```
<script>
$("#jstree").jstree().bind('ready.jstree', function(event, data) {
    $("#jstree").jstree('select_node', '{{concept_id}}');
    $("#jstree").jstree('open_node', '{{concept_id}}', function(e, d) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.parents.length; i++) {
            $("#jstree").jstree('open_node', e.parents[i]);
        };
    });

});
</script>
```

Here is the second:

```
<script>
$('#jstree').jstree().on("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
    document.location = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true).children('a').attr('href');
});
</script>
```

The first block allows me to open up the tree to a specific node on page load. The second block allows my links to be clickable, since they are not otherwise.

How can I combine .bind() and .on() with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var jsTree = $("#jstree");
var PageLoadlock = false;
jsTree.jstree().bind('ready.jstree', function(event, data) {
                        PageLoadlock = true;
                        jsTree.jstree('select_node', '{{concept_id}}');
                        jsTree.jstree('open_node', '{{concept_id}}', function(e, d) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < e.parents.length; i++) {
                            $("#jstree").jstree('open_node', e.parents[i]);
                        };
                    });
                 }).on("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
                        if (PageLoadlock) { PageLoadlock = !PageLoadlock; return}
                        document.location = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true).children('a').attr('href');
                    });
```

something like this, add .jstree().on before or after .jstree().bind, the order does not count.

**Update**
Added lock for slect_node.jstree if the event is generated programaticly

Comment: If I do that, the page starts reloading over and over again. Other wise it works. Any ideas?

Comment: one moment, missed that

Comment: check update, but I have a question, why are u reloading the entire page, use a ajax call or something.

Comment: Basically because I'm a hack and I don't know what i'm doing. This works so I am very grateful for you adding some javascript expertise to the situation. I'm building an app for my business because I can't afford a real developer, but one day when I'm rich and famous I'll pay someone big bucks to convert the whole thing into a beautiful angular app.